# double serialize function checkbook in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, serialization, input

I have 3 checkbook with 3 option answer every checkbook. I'm saving every checkbook using serialize, but I can't save the data if the check book has 1 more answer.

```
<?php if( ! empty($questiontype)): ?>
    <label>Answer Type</label><br> 
    <label>A</label>
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php foreach($questiontype as $key => $val): ?>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"  >
        <input name="meta_answertype[][]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" type="checkbox"<?php if($key == @$meta['answertype'][0][0]) echo 'checked'; ?> /> <?php echo $val; ?>
    </label>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
      <label>B</label>
    <div class="form-group">
       <?php foreach($questiontype as $key => $val): ?>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input name="meta_answertype[][]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" type="checkbox"<?php if($key == @$meta['answertype'][1][1]) echo 'checked'; ?> /> <?php echo $val; ?>
    </label>
      <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
      <label>C</label>
    <div class="form-group">
     <?php foreach($questiontype as $key => $val): ?>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input name="meta_answertype[][]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" type="checkbox"<?php if($key == @$meta['answertype'][2][2]) echo 'checked'; ?> /> <?php echo $val; ?>
    </label>  
         <?php endforeach; ?>                                    
    </div>
           <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can't quite figure out the question.  Could you please try and be more specific.

Comment: http://sedekahcelengan.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/w.png